Prove that $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ is not reflexive by finidng counter example to James' theorem
Let $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ denote the $L^1$ space over the real numbers with the Lebesgue measure.
By James' theorem (in easier direction) we know that if $X$ is a refexive Banach space, then every continuous linear functional $x' \in X'$ attains its norm for some $x \in X$ with $\lVert x \rVert _X = 1$, that is: $x'(x) = \lVert x' \rVert _{X'}$.
We can use this result for proving that $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ is not reflexive, by explicitly constructing an element which will violate this.
I have seen such counter examples for other spaces like $\ell^1$, $L^1 [0, 1]$ and so on, but I can not construct a counter example for $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Any ideas on what could work?

What's your example for $L^1[0,1]$?

The example from the $L^1(0,1)$ can be used here as well, e.g., $x'(x) = \int_0^1 tx(t)dt$
